# Two axis with same scale

Tags: pgfplots

The following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotsset{
    width=8cm,
    height=6cm,
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0, xmax=14
  }

  \begin{axis}[ymode=log,
    axis y line*=left,
    ymin=1e-6,ymax=1e1]

    \addplot [color=black, solid, domain=0:14]
    { x * exp(- x )  };
  \end{axis}

  \begin{axis}[
    y dir=reverse, ymode=log,
    % ymin=1e0,ymax=1e7,
    axis x line*=none,
    axis y line*=right]

    \addplot [color=black, dashed, domain=0:14] { exp(x)  };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

produces the following plot.

[image: MWE output]

The problem for me is that the scale of the second axis is different from the first. If I uncomment `ymin=1e0,ymax=1e7` in the second axis, the scale is corrected (at least it looks that way).

Is there a way to automate this process? Specifically, 
for (`ymin_1`, `ymax_1`) and (`ymin_2`, `ymax_2`) being the min/max y value for the two axes. I want `ymin_2` for the second axis to be deduced automatically from the plot in the second axis (as it is now), but `ymax_2` should be `ymax_2 = ymin_2 * ymax_1/ymin_1`